# Modify each block entry to call method on block argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, view-components

In one of my views, I rendered a table with a helper method, so the view (haml) looked like this:

```
= table do
  - action "Add"
  - column :id
  - column :name
```

After I changed the helper and used the ViewComponent lib instead, I need to call it the following way:

```
= table do |t|
  - t.action "Add"
  - t.column :id
  - t.column :name
```

I wondered if it's possible to convert the block in example 1 to the block in example 1 in a helper method, so I don't need to rewrite every view that uses a table.

The helper method would look like:

```rb
def table(*args, **kwargs, &block)
  # ...
  render TableComponent.new(*args, **kwargs, &new_block)
end
```

Comment: Do you really have that many views so that you want to spend time on a fools errand instead of fixing the original problem? Use a regex in your editor to find the offenses and fix them.

Comment: @max changing the views is not the problem, but I this would keep the usage of this helper consistent with the project

Comment: In Ruby, a block is an anonymous function. What you are proposing would be code that could take a function, modify that function in place based on the unknown contents of the function and then forward the new block on. While Ruby does have meta-programming, I don't see how this could be done. I agree with @max  that it seems that it would be easier to use regex or write code that reads your source code and updates it  than to try and write this helper.

Comment: you are asking for a DSL, e.g. some `instance_eval` probably

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify your example to this:

```rb
class Table
  def initialize
    @rows = []
  end

  def action(name)
    @rows << "Action #{name}"
  end

  def column(name)
    @rows << "Column #{name}"
  end

  def to_s
    "Table:\n======\n#{@rows.join("\n")}"
  end
end

def table(&block)
  t = Table.new
  block.call(t)
  t
end

puts(
  table do |t|
    t.action "Add"
    t.column :id
    t.column :name
  end
)
```

That gives:

```
Table:
======
Action Add
Column id
Column name
```

Now you want to do:

```rb
  table do
    action "Add"
    column :id
    column :name
  end
```

So you want to have the body of the block be in the same context as the instance (e.g. like being in a Table instance), so:

```rb
def table(&block)
  t = Table.new
  t.instance_eval(&block)
  t
end
```

(that's how most Domain Specific Languages are made :) )